# How to change password in laravel-4 with auth

Tags: laravel-4

I am using laravel-4 auth component . I want to make a function which will change user password . I have my view as follows :

password - Text-box ;
new_password - Text-box;
confirm_new_password - Text-box

I also have checked manual for password reset , but in that doc(http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset) they are sending mail for password reset .
View is as follows :

```
   @extends('layouts.main') 
@section('title') Change Password 
@stop
@section('content')
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'users/user-password-change', 'class'=>'block small center login')) }}
<h3 class="">Change Password</h3>
   <h6>Please change your password below.</h6>
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Old Password')) }}
    {{ Form::password('new_password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'New Password')) }}
    {{ Form::password('confirm_new_password', array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Confirm New Password')) }}


    {{ Form::submit('Register', array('class'=>'k-button'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Controller code is as follows :

```
public function postUserPasswordChange(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$change_password_rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $user=new UserEventbot;
        $user->password=Hash::make(Input::get('new_password'));
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('users/change-password');
    }else {
        return Redirect::to('users/change-password')->with('message', 'The following errors occurred')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Please help me on this , how to first match this password with database table users , and then  the whole process .
Thank you .

Comment: What is in your controller? what is inside update function.

Comment: i have added controller code in question , please check this .

Comment: yes user is logged in .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try the following:**

```
public function postUserPasswordChange(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$change_password_rules);
    if($validator->passes()){

        $user = UserEventbot::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('new_password'));
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('users/change-password');
    }else {
        return Redirect::to('users/change-password')->with('message', 'The following errors occurred')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , it works now , thank you . There is one thing left how to match password with database password .

Answer (score 8):

To match current user password with password in database you can do something like this,

```
// retrieve the authenticated user
$user = Auth::user();
```

Retrieve the current password specified by the user inside the form,

```
$current_password = Input::get('current_password');
```

We can see if the current password has bee specified and check against the hashed password as follows,

```
if (strlen($current_password) > 0 && !Hash::check($current_password, $user->password)) {
        return Redirect::to('/user/edit-profile')->withErrors('Please specify the good current password');
    }
```

Important thing to note here is the function

**Hash::check(CURRENT_PASSWORD_ENTERED_IN_FORM, HASHED_VERSION_OF_PASSWORD_STORED_IN_AUTH_USER)**

Finally, if it's all good you can update the current user password inside Auth and in database as follows,

```
// authenticated user
$user = Auth::user();
$user->password = Hash::make($new_password);

// finally we save the authenticated user
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my own solution, I have 3 inputs = old_password, password, password_confirmation, form with action=post.
Validator check requirements, hash checks if Old password matches

```
public function changePassword() 
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $rules = array(
        'old_password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:6,16',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|between:6,16|confirmed'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::action('UserController@show',$user->id)->withErrors($validator);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (!Hash::check(Input::get('old_password'), $user->password)) 
        {
            return Redirect::action('UserController@show',$user->id)->withErrors('Your old password does not match');
        }
        else
        {
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::action('UserController@show',$user->id)->withMessage("Password have been changed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try the following changed**

```
public function postUserPasswordChange(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$change_password_rules);
    if($validator->passes()){
        $user = UserEventbot::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        if(Hash::check(Input::get('password'), $user->getAuthPassword())) {
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('new_password'));
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('users/change-password')->with('message','Your password has been changed');
        }
    }
    return Redirect::to('users/change-password')->with('message', 'The following errors occurred')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

You should exclude withInput() in term of password.Hope this help